# Are parameters passed to subprocess safe in any way from code injection?

Tags: python, subprocess

Are parameters passed to subprocess safe in any way from code injection?

I am building a small python program to do some movie file tagging. For ease, I am passing the tag info to AtomicParsley (on Windows) using subprocess.call(). The tag information is an online source, retrieved automatically. If some individual were to place code in the tags (i.e. replaced the actors with some sort of rd term), would subprocess be safe from that execution? This is more of a conceptual question than a question about the specifics of the language.

The subprocess.call is executed with ['AtomicParsley',filename,'--tag1',tag1_info,(...)]. Since the first part of the command is guaranteed to be the name of the AP executable and the second is guaranteed to be a valid filename, I should think any malicious code inside the metainfo database would just be written as a string to the appropriate tag (i.e. the Actor's name would be del C:\Windows). Do those seem like reasonable assumptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you use a list of parameters and leave `shell` set to False, yes, the parameters are safe from code injection. They will not be parsed by a shell and thus not subject to any code execution opportunities.

Note that on Windows, the chances of using code injection are already mitigated by the fact that a `CreateProcess` call is used.

Comment: Well not really, they could trigger some bugs and cause a lot of nasty things, the subprocess could have a lot of security bugs...

Comment: If the  child process itself has security flaws, all bets are off. But if it doesn't, then your python code didn't open any new ones.